# Android, AWS Cognito Google OAuth authentication goes unauthenticated using CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth

I login using Google OAuth2 in my Android app using the following code:

In my Login activities onCreate method I have:

```
    googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            //requestIdToken takes the google cloud console's project's WEB (not Android) openID client ID.
            .requestIdToken("my client id")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) oAuth.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
    signInButton.setScopes(googleSignInOptions.getScopeArray());

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(oAuth)
            .enableAutoManage(oAuth, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Log.d("GoogleOAuth", "Connection failed\n" + connectionResult.getErrorMessage() );
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to connect to Google", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .build();
```

I register an onClick listener to the login button which calls:

```
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
```

I get the activity result:

```
public void onActivityResult(OAuth oAuth, Context context, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            String idToken = account.getIdToken(); //this has a value

            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
            logins.put("accounts.google.com", token);
            AWSCommunicator.setLogins(oAuth, logins, account);
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "failed to login" + result.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("GoogleAuth", "Bad requestCode: " + requestCode);
    }
}
```

Now everything runs great, it all seems to work fine. Here is some of the logs I see.

```
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Identity id is changed
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Saving credentials to SharedPreferences
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
```

Everything works great.  I'm authenticated and I can make authenticated calls to my API gateway endpoints (using an auto-generated SDK from AWS Api Gateway).

Now an hour later, I try to make calls and that token has expired.  How do I go about getting a new token?  And then how do I refresh Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the new Id token from google from the refresh token vended by Google. This doc might be helpful. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2

To refresh the Cognito credentials, you just need to keep the credentialsProvider up to date with the latest token from IdP (Google Oauth in this case.). Once credentials expire, it will automatically refresh if CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider has the latest token.